# How to animate a UIImageView with array of NSUrl intead array of UIImage?

Tags: animation, uiimageview, uiimage, nsurl, sdwebimage

In my app,i am using SDWebImageView, i have to show a list of user in a table and every user have 6 images. So i have to show every images.
I am using below code to animate image on a screen.

```
[smallDpImageV setImage:[UIImage animatedImageWithImages:_dynamicImageArray duration:time]];
[smallDpImageV startAnimating];
```

it receive an array of uiimage here every image is created by a URL. but for tableview i don't want to create multiple arrays on uiimage.

Can i do it with NSUrl ?. like this

```
[imgV sd_setImageWithURL:[dict valueForKey:@"thumb_nail"] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1447851886_male3.png"]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer with SDWebImageView.

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in [mainDict valueForKey:@"profile_pic"]) {
    [imgArr addObject:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict valueForKey:@"thumb_nail"]]]];
}
if (imgArr.count >0) {
    [cell.imgViewUserImage sd_setAnimationImagesWithURLs:imgArr];
    cell.imgViewUserImage.animationDuration = imgArr.count*2;
    [cell.imgViewUserImage startAnimating];
}
```